# scheduled task from plesk "unable to resolve host address"

Tags: scheduled-tasks, wget, plesk, chron

Under my virtualHost, I need to schedule a task. Done it from plesk , and working till a week ago.

I have tried adding another task, and then it stop worked.

The task is wget http://mydomain.it/cron/scrape.php . and obviously called from external works without any problem.

What can be the issue?

Plesk subscription ( fake) ==> mydomain.it

--2015-05-30 06:30:01-- http://mydomain.it/cron/scrape.php
Resolving www.mydomain.it (mydomain.it)... failed: Name or service not known.
wget: unable to resolve host address `mydomain.it'

Comment: if I do wget from SSH , no problem to find the domain required :(

Comment: Giuseppe, have you found a workaround or a solution to it? Having the same issue...

Comment: no and that's really a bad thing, I finally called with easycron